# How would I get to get the answer of the screen value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a calculator, and I'm having the numbers appear on my screen. I want to know how to calculate the number on the screen using eval(screen.value), but I haven't had any experience using it. I also want to know how I would make it give an error message if there is no numbers entered. and the final thing I want to know which I have no knowledge of, or any experience is how to clear the value if I press the C value.

Thank you,

```js
//3.
//Changing colors of opertion colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green" //Makes Color Green

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"//Makes Color Red

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"//Makes Color Blue

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"//Makes Color Yellow


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier for you to change a colour of one button
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What number buttons are pressed
var numButton = document.querySelectorAll(".btn8");
var showNum = document.querySelector(".screen8");


numButton.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    let view = event.target.dataset.num;
    showNum.value += view;
  });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//When equal is pressed
var equalButton = document.querySelector(".btn8")

equalButton.addEventListener(function(button){
 button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   showNum.push(eval(screen.value));
   if(screen.value === ""){
     alert("Please Enter a Value");
   }
  });
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 7rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-kground: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 
<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">



</head>

<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
 <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="calcScreeng" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>


  </div>



 </section>

 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not following everything here, but you could do an onkeyup handler to look for that 'c' or 'C' and do something.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the value, set the value like so: `showNum.value = ""`:
In your code, you should have some if statements to differentiate the "C" and the equals sign:

```js
if(event.target.innerHTML == "C"){
  return showNum.value = "";
} else if (event.target.innerHTML == "=") {
  return;
}
// the rest of your code
```

Also, HTML inputs do not have a `push` method (`push` is for adding stuff to arrays, not for appending text). To append your eval'd result, just concatenate text:

```js
showNum.value = showNum.value + "=" + eval(showNum.value);
```

To send errors if there are no numbers entered, use an if statement, checking if the value is empty:

```js
if(showNum.value == ""){
  return alert("Please enter a number");
}
```

Your code was almost right, except that the if statement came after evaluating the code, and that you checked `screen.value` instead of `showNum.value` This didn't work because `screen` is not a defined variable in your code.

A few more issues in your code:

- the query selector `.btn8` does not match just the equals button. (all the buttons in your HTML use `.btn8`) Instead, use `#equals` or `document.getElementById("equals")`
- events do not have an `addEventListener` method. Your code may have been a mistake from copying the for-loop before.

Working snippet:

```js
//3.
//Changing colors of operation colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green" //Makes Color Green

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"//Makes Color Red

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"//Makes Color Blue

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"//Makes Color Yellow


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier for you to change a colour of one button
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What number buttons are pressed
var numButton = document.querySelectorAll(".btn8");
var showNum = document.querySelector(".screen8");


numButton.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.innerHTML == "C"){
      return showNum.value = "";
    } else if (event.target.innerHTML == "=") {
      return;
    }
    let view = event.target.dataset.num;
    showNum.value += view;
  });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//When equal is pressed
var equalButton = document.querySelector("#equals")
equalButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(showNum.value == ""){
    return alert("Please Enter a Value");
  }
  showNum.value = showNum.value + "=" + eval(showNum.value);
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 7rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-kground: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 
<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">



</head>

<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
 <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="calcScreeng" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>


  </div>



 </section>

 
</body>

</html>
```